# iOS: how to perform bluetooth communication?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I establish a bluetooth communication between an accessory (already equipped with the authentication chip) and an iOS app?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on rckoenes' answer:

Unless you're the original manufacturer of the accessory that contains the authentication chip, you likely won't have the correct credentials to use it from your code.

Apple provides the external accessory SDK to manufacturers so they can develop their products. They don't provide it to third parties to develop software against other third party products.

The only way you'll be able to successfully communicate with the accessory using bluetooth is if you have the valid authentication keys and the external accessory SDK. If you're missing those, you can't do it.

GameKit is a more generic way of using bluetooth, but it won't work for external accessories.

The only other thing I can think of would be to jailbreak the phone, etc, but I'm not prepared to help with that.

Comment: Thank you for your deeper explanation. Mine was a bit short.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way to use Bluetooth is via GameKit.

Comment: So its possible to connection use Bonjour via bleutooth with out GameKit. Any change you can direct me to an example or documentation about this.